# Eloquent model not updating updated_at timestamp

Tags: php, laravel, timestamp, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.1. To make it simple, I have the following code

Migration:

```
Schema::create('sitemap_data', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // Primary and foreign keys
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('postUrl');
    // Database functions
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And this is the code somewhere else I'm using

```
$sitemapData = SitemapData::firstOrNew([
                'postUrl' => $post
            ]);
$sitemapData->save();
```

Now, according to the Laravel documentation

> Again, the updated_at timestamp will automatically be updated, so there is no need to manually set its value

The updated_at value should be updated in the table. However, this is not happening.

It get's only set on the first insert, but not on updating. When I do it manually, like this

```
$sitemapData = SitemapData::firstOrNew([
                    'postUrl' => $post
                ]);
$sitemapData->updated_at = Carbon::now();
$sitemapData->save();
```

it works. However, the docs say this should happend automatically, so what is wrong here?

I've searched some sites on stackoverflow for this question, but the ones I found where for Laravel 3 or 4.1, 4.2 etc.

How would I do that correctly?

Comment: If there's no changes to the record data, then it won't be updated..... that's just unnecessary overhead.... and `$sitemapData = SitemapData::firstOrNew([
                'postUrl' => $post
            ]);
$sitemapData->save();` doesn't change the record data in any way

Comment: Ah okay! I thought the updated_at gets updated regardless of changes or not. You are right, that I didn't make changes, I just wanted to check if it works or not. Thanks. Now this makes sense

Comment: No, this is where Laravel is trying to be clever, and avoid the expense of a database call if it isn't necessary

Answer (score 53, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, if the model did not change the timestamps wont be updated. However if you need to update them, or want to check if everything is working fine use `$model->touch()` - more [here](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_touch)

Comment: how about `created_at`. I came across a error where `created_at` was set to 0 but `updated_at` was correct. It may be possible that `updated_at` was updated later. However I'm not able to regenerate this issue. It was just a random case.

Comment: Eloquent method touch doc: https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_touch

Answer (score 8):

It is possible actually:

```
$model->updated_at = Carbon::now();
$model->save(['timestamps' => FALSE]);
```

That will properly save the `updated_at` to now. If you're not sure if any of the model's columns have changed, but you do want to update the `updated_at` regardless - this is the way to go.

Comment: I prefer this solution to the accepted answer, because it lets me fake the time in tests (with Carbon::setTestNow).

Answer (score 7):

This is not the case in the question, but same issue will happen if you're using Query Builder instead of Eloquent Model.

If you do

```
DB::table('users')->where()->update()
```

instead of

```
User::where()->update()
```

updated_at will not be updated.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah what *Musterknabe* has done is correct but he should also check his model **SitemapData.php** it should have to have set `$timestamps = true;`

```
<?php 

 class SitemapData extends Eloquent {

        public $timestamps = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go to phpmyadmin and select your db and select the table
tap on SQL tab above and type for example  something like this:

```
UPDATE `boshogriq_table` SET  `updated_at`= DATE_ADD(`created_at`, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
 WHERE  `updated_at` > DATE_ADD(`created_at`, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

run it by go button.
**Laravel won't allow you do this**