# How to update row and return updated_at?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I attempted to update row and return value of `updated_at` instantly after:

```
$product = ProductModel::where("Id", $id)->update(["Status" => 0]);

return $product->updated_at;
```

How to do that correct?

Also can I do this globally for each update?

Comment: For global I assume I have to use update events

Comment: If you have different primary key (not `id`), you sholud look into overriding `$primaryKey` on your model. In the [eloquent docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent) search for text `Primary Keys`, and read more about it. That will allow you to use methods `find()` and `findOrFail()`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `update` function is intended to do a *bulk* update, against however many rows your query returns. It could be zero, it could be one, it could be a thousand. As such, its return value is just a boolean "did it work?" value.

Since you're looking to update a single row:

```
$product = ProductModel::where("Id", $id)->first();
$product->Status = 0;
$product->save();

return $product->updated_at;
```

You really should tell Laravel about your custom primary key, so you can use `ProductModel::find($id)` for cleaner code.

Side note: If you have a single ProductModel in `$product`, and you use `update()` on it, you can do `$product->refresh()` to re-fetch its data from the database.

Comment: But I will check this: $product->refresh()

Comment: @OPV Then you either haven't used my code as written, or the `Status` value was already `0`.

Answer (score 2):

The `updated_at` field will be touched automatically after an update operation and you don't have to do that manually, if you want to touch the `updated_at` timestamp in other times, use `touch()` method as following snippet:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->touch();
```

Comment: @OPV Yes, `update()` method returns a boolean value, that has not `updated_at` property

Comment: It does not work, `dd($product->touch());` returns false

Answer (score 1):

This line of code will return you a boolean. True for a successful update, false for no updates.

```
$product = ProductModel::where("Id", $id)->update(["Status" => 0]);
```

Try this:

```
$product = ProductModel::find($id);

$product->update(["Status" => 0]);

return $product->updated_at;
```

Comment: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$updated_at` on `$product = ProductModel::where('IdProduct', $id);

        $product->update(["Status" => 0]);`

Comment: You didn't follow the instructions. It's ProductModel::find($id) or better findOrFail($id).

Comment: I have different key, not id, also I have additional where cond

Answer (score 0):

check out this:

```
$product = ProductModel::where("Id", $id)->first();
$product->Status = 0;
$product->save();

return $product->updated_at;
```

Comment: If model already had `Status == 0`, and there was no update, `updated_at` will not change. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30846058/3226121).

Comment: Sure, but I have Status 1, then I see it was updated to 0, but return old updated_at

Comment: use `$product->touch();` after saving model

Comment: @tuytoosh No, you generally don't want to do that, as `touch()` will *update* the `updated_at` value. It's an extra query, is unnecessary, and makes the `updated_at` value potentially subtly incorrect. `$product->refresh()` is a better approach if you've used `update()` and want to get the new values.

Comment: @ceejayoz As mentioned above, "if the model did not change, the timestamps won't be updated"

Comment: @tuytoosh Nor should they, right? `updated_at` should reflect the time the row was last updated. Touching it when *not* making an update is the "subtly incorrect" bit I'm referring to.

Comment: @ceejayoz The problem is that the user (OPV) wants to be :)

Comment: @tuytoosh That's not how I'm reading OP's question. OP could easily do that by adding `'updated_at' => now()` to their `update()` array, which would avoid the extra query `touch()` does.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, by query optimization insight, you are right :)