# Can't update column 'Updated_at' in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm still new to this laravel framework, so I was having this issue where I was unable to update the column "updated_at" which is automatically created by laravel migration. I want to change the value to the current time when I press a button. I have tried multiple ways from similar questions but it doesn't seem to work, like using '->update()','->save()', or '->touch()'.

**syntax to update in Controller**

```
$check = \DB::table('queueTable')->where('category',$catName2)->where('status','Active')->where('skipped','0')->whereDate('created_at','=',now())->orderBy('queue','ASC')->limit(1);
$counter = \DB::table('queueTable')->where('category',$catName2)->where('status','Inactive')->whereDate('created_at','=',now())->count();
\DB::table('CurrentQueue')->where('id', 2)->update(['DoneQueue' => $counter+1]);
$check->update(['status' => 'Inactive']);
$check->update(['updated_at' => now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
```

**my migration**

```
Schema::create('queueTable', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();
  $table->string('category');
  $table->integer('queue')->default('0');
  $table->string('status');
  $table->integer('skipped')->default('0');
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

it'd be much appreciated if someone could kindly explain where I'm going wrong.
Thanks in advance.

I want to update the value of "updated_at" to the current time when I press a button

Comment: `updated_at` field updates itself on each update to the database (specific column). You don't need to update it manually.

Comment: if you call `$movel->save()` or `$model->update()`, the `updated_at` will be automatically updated

Comment: Look at the documentation: *"By default, Eloquent expects created_at and updated_at columns to exist on your model's corresponding database table. Eloquent will automatically set these column's values when models are created or updated."* [Eloquent: Timestamps](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#timestamps)

Comment: but for some reason my updated_at column doesnt updated automatically, thats why im asking is there any possible way that i could alter the table

Comment: it's only inserting a value (timestamps) to the 'created_at' and 'updated_at' column at the same time when data is recorded to the table for the first time.

Comment: Are you sure `$check` is actually a result?  Because `->whereDate('created_at','=',now())` seems like a highly risky way to select something. Maybe `$check` does not match anything, and so your `update()` does nothing?

Comment: @Don'tPanic , `$check` does return the value that i want and i've used var dump to verify, but if you think that might be the cause, i'll try to find other way to get the result.

Comment: [It seems that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62204483/6089612) automatic updating of timestamps only works if you are using Models, not when using query builder as you are. [The documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#timestamps) confirms this: "*Eloquent will automatically set these column's values when models are created or updated*".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eloquent model not updating updated\_at timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844792/eloquent-model-not-updating-updated-at-timestamp)

Comment: Yes it does, after some tries it does seem that my `updated_at` column not updating because i use query builder instead of Model. Thank you for your kind explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update you record using Model, it will update "updated_at" automatically.
Change code i your controller:

```
$check = queueTable::where('category',$catName2)->where('status','Active')->where('skipped','0')->whereDate('created_at','=',now());

$counter = $check->count();
$check = ->orderBy('queue','ASC')->first();

CurrentQueue::where('id', 2)->save(['DoneQueue' => $counter+1]);
$check->save(['status' => 'Inactive']);
```

***Note: If you are not using model, first create Models  queueTable, CurrentQueue***

Comment: Okay thanks, will try this method, i'll get back with the ressult